# How to add script, if the first column is empty do the next row or do nothing?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a list on Google Sheets.

Where in column A (email address), column B (email message) and column C (script to prevent send duplicate email)

What I need is, whenever column A is empty, then do nothing while if column C written "EMAIL_SENT" skip this row and go to next row.

```
enter code here
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

function sendEmails2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = 10;

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3); 

var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0];
var message = row[1];
var emailSent = row[2];
if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) {
  var subject = 'Customer Melakukan Check Out';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
}

enter code here
```

Any ideas on how I can get something like this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow=2;
  var numRows=10;
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,3); 
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
    var row=data[i];
    var emailAddress=row[0];
    var message=row[1];
    var emailSent=row[2];
    if (emailSent!="EMAIL_SENT" && emailAddress) {
      var subject='Customer Melakukan Check Out';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Using column D in message:

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow=2;
  var numRows=10;
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,4); 
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
    var row=data[i];
    var emailAddress=row[0];
    var message=row[1]+row[3];
    var emailSent=row[2];
    if (emailSent!="EMAIL_SENT" && emailAddress) {
      var subject='Customer Melakukan Check Out';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Cooper.

From my script before, I make column B as an email message. Is it possible add column as an email message, like to make column D and column D as an email message as well?